# How to join on timestamp columns with tolerance

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, zoho, fuzzy-comparison

How can I allow a tolerance of 1 - 10 sec?

I have 2 tables that have timestamps, yet are off by 1-10 seconds. I am using the inner join to compare them. I have phone numbers (columns) in both tables that match up but cant make them match up with the timestamps (time only). To allow a certain tolerance I could use an expression like `cast(DateCreated as Time) = cast(TIMESTAMP as time) + 5`. But I don't want to be doing this for every second.

```
SELECT Time_To_Sec(cast("table1_DateCreated" as time)) as DateCreated 
     , Time_To_Sec(cast("table2"."Timestamp" as time)) as Timestampe
     , "Direction","FromTW", "ToTW", "table2"."ANI","table2"."CALL ID"
     , "table2"."Disposition"
FROM "calls and time"
INNER JOIN "table2" on cast(DateCreated as Time)=cast(TIMESTAMP as time)+5
                   and FromTW="table2"."ANI"
```

I would like to see the following results if possible:

```
table1(DateCreated)  |  table2(Timestamp)  | compared results
---------------------+---------------------+-----------------
5000                 |  5005               |  table3
5001                 |  5009               |  table3
5001                 |  5050               |  not in table3
```

If the condition is met then it will be sent to table 3 but if does not meet the condition the it will not be sent to table 3.

Using Zoho reports, therefore I'm not sure what type of database they are using. Postgres, MySQL, etc.

Comment: Postgres or MySQL? It can't be both at the same time.

Comment: I dont know what ZOHO report likes more but mysql work most of the time. lets try Mysql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If timestamps in *both* tables can be `off by 1-10 seconds`, then it follows logically that the maximum tolerance for a match is **20 sceonds** (+/- 10 on each side).

Tested in **Postgres**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   "calls and time" t1
JOIN   table2 t2 ON t2."TIMESTAMP" BETWEEN t1."DateCreated" - interval '20 sec'
                                       AND t1."DateCreated" + interval '20 sec';
WHERE  t1."FromTW" = t2."ANI"  -- FromTW or "FromTW" ?
```

This is a [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) expression that allows to use an index on `x`:

```
x BETWEEN y - interval '20 sec'
      AND y + interval '20 sec'
```

`"calls and time"`, `"TIMESTAMP"`, `"FromTW"` are *extremely unfortunate identifiers*, btw. Stick to legal, unquoted names to save some trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Check the absolute difference of the two timestamps, which'd be in pseudo-code:

```
if (abs($timestamp1 - $timestamp2) <= $tolerance) { ... }
```

Comment: i see the logic. i will try it out.